# Cake php3.0 xampp 3.2.1 error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hey I had installed xampp on windows xampp control panel 3.2.1 and I am getting this error :

> Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in  G:\xampp\htdocs\hw\config\bootstrap.php on line 38

I had changed `httpd.conf` and uncomment  this line

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

and change directory attributes :

```
  <Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
   </Directory>
```

to this and restarted the apache and I am still getting this message Fatal error:

> You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in G:\xampp\htdocs\hw\config\bootstrap.php on line 38

Comment: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html**

Comment: `mod_rewrite` has nothing to do with this error. You should uncomment `extension=php_intl.dll`. Also `Deny from all` is going to deny all, including yourself. So once you are past this error, you will run into that. You might want to change that section to `Require local`

Answer (score 1):

If you have already Change ;extension=php_intl.dll to extension=php_intl.dll (remove the semicolon) in php.ini

Still same error comes.

In both XAMPP and WAMP, mcrypt and mbstring extensions are working by default.

In XAMPP, intl extension is included but you have to uncomment extension=php_intl.dll in php.ini and restart the server through the XAMPP Control Panel.

In WAMP, the intl extension is “activated” by default but not working. To make it work you have to go to php folder (by default) C:\wamp\bin\php\php{version}, copy all the files that looks like icu*.dll and paste them into the apache bin directory C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin. Then restart all services and it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You may get the correct ans here :

In both XAMPP and WAMP, `mcrypt` and `mbstring` extensions are working by default.

In XAMPP, `intl` extension is included but in the php.ini you have to uncomment:

`extension=php_intl.dll`

and restart the server through the XAMPP Control Panel.

In WAMP, the `intl` extension is “activated” by default but not working. To make it work you have to go to the php folder (by default):

`C:\wamp\bin\php\php{version}`

copy all the files that looks like `icu*.dll` and paste them into the apache bin directory

`C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin.`

Then restart all services and it should be OK.